# Inverse $f^ {-1}$ of floor function

Tags: discrete-mathematics, ceiling-and-floor-functions

How to solve:
Let $f: R \to R$ be defined by $f(x)=\lfloor x \rfloor$.
Find $f^{-1}(B)$ for B={0,1}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f^{-1}$ here does not stand fo the inverse function, which obviously does not exist. It stands for the pre-image of the set $B$. The real numbers $x$ with floor equal to zero or one are those in the interval $[0,2)$